# PHP : How to get sum of multidimensionnal arrays with specific keys?

Tags: php

I would like to know how to get the sum of some key values of multi-dimensional arrays, knowing that some keys are variables; here is an example of the situation :

The array could be written like this :

`$array[$dim1][$dim2][$dim3][$dim4] = $variable_value;`

$dim1, 2, 3 and 4 are arrays with dimensions, and we don't know the name of the $dim1, 2, 3 and 4.

We want the sum of all $variable_value of each dimensions, but we can't do `array_sum($array[$dim1][$dim2][$dim3][$dim4])` because the $dim are not known.

The algorithm I need to find must permit me to apply filters on the sums, like "get the sum of all the $variable_value where $dim3 = $variableX...", so a function like this :

```
function array_sum_filter($array, $dimension, [$filter_on_key_value])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: $filter_on_key_value - is that some sort of generic filter language you're trying to get us to implement here? ie, do you want to be able to filter by any arbitrary value for any arbitrary dim1, dim2, dim3, or dim4 dimension value? Also, do you want sums of matched variables at each level (eg, for each combination of the other dims?) I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve is all!

Answer (score 0):

use for/foreach loops for looping through the multidimensional array and an if statement to check if $dim3 = $variableX...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`

```
$sum = 0;
$specific = 0;
$array = array();
$array["A"]["B"]["C"]["D"] = 5;
$array["A"]["B"]["K"]["D"] = 3;
$array["A"]["C"] = 2;

$array_obj = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
foreach ( $array_obj as $key => $value ) {
    $sum += $value;

    if ($key == "D")
        $specific += $value;
}

echo $sum, PHP_EOL;
echo $specific, PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
 10
 8
```